# I want to display data from CoreData into a tableview

Tags: swift, core-data

I want to display data from CoreData into a tableview, im working on favoris, im adding my events on favoris and i want to display it inside a tableview, there is my code :

```
   var lists : [NSManagedObject] = [] {
     didSet {
           favorisEventTableView.reloadData()
       }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var favorisEventTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
        favorisEventTableView.dataSource = self
             favorisEventTableView.delegate = self
             loadFavoris()
          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         favorisEventTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                        return 1

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lists.count

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = favorisEventTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FavorisCell")
               let contentView = cell?.viewWithTag(0)
               let eventId = contentView?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel     
                  let item = lists[indexPath.row]

        eventId.text = String((item.value(forKey: "id_event") as! Int))

        return cell!
    }

    func loadFavoris() {
         let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
         let coreContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
         let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Favoris")
         do {
             lists = try coreContext!.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print(lists)
         } catch let error as NSError {
             print(error.userInfo)
         }
     }
```

But it's not displaying anything, maybe the problem on the add function ? im sure it works cause i get "saved" on the console, any help please?
PS: entity "Favoris" has only one attribute "id_event" which is an integer

Comment: in another controller and it works fine, but i need to reload data on tableview to save latest add or delete

Comment: You should use `NSFetchedResultsController` or the dedicated API of `UITableView` which inserts and deletes the rows with nice animation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `loadFavoris` inside `viewDidLoad` not `cellForRowAt`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      favorisEventTableView.dataSource = self
      favorisEventTableView.delegate = self
      loadFavoris()
}
```

Comment: thank you it works, but when i add an event to favoris i have to reopen the app to get it inside the tableview, do i need an update function about entity "Favoris" ?

Comment: you can call ` loadFavoris()` inside `viewDidAppear`

Comment: i need to reload data on tableview to save latest add or delete, because when i add an event to favoris it did not appear when im running the app, i need to reopen the app to see the last changes on tableview

Answer (score -1):

You need to reload your table view every change on your list. you can do it like that

```
var lists : [NSManagedObject] = [] {
 didSet {
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Don't forget assign the delegate and dataSource protocols of tableView and fetch the data in viewDidLoad() function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      tableView.delegate = self
      tableView.dataSource = self
      loadFavoris()
}
```

Comment: it did not work, and im getting "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on line let id = (item.value(forKey: "id_event") as! Int)